# Actualizar datatable luego de un insert

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Mi pregunta puntual es: ¿Por que para refrescar los datos de un datable tengo que limpiar y construir el proyecto nuevamente?

Inserto los registros sin problemas , pero al momento de verlos en el datatable la fila en donde debería ir ese registro aparece vacía. (no aparece apellido, nombre, dni, dirección).

clienteList.xhtml

```
<f:view> 
    <h:form id="form" > 
        <h1><h:outputText value="Listado de Clientes"/></h1> 

        <p:dataTable id="datatable" paginator="true" 
                     rows="7" value="#{clienteDataController.clienteList}" var="item" 
                     rowKey="#{item.idpersona}" 
                     selectionMode="single" 
                     selection="#{clienteDataController.selected}" 
                     > 
            <p:ajax event="rowSelect" 
                    oncomplete="PF('editwidgetVar').show();" 
                    update=":form:growl,:form:displayEdit"/> 


            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Apellido"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.persona.apellido}"/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Nombres"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.persona.nombre}"/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="DNI"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.persona.numeroDocumento}"/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Dirección"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.persona.direccion}"/>

            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Télefono"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.persona.telefono}"/>

            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Fecha de Alta"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.fechaAlta}">
                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"/>
                </h:outputText>
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Fecha de Baja"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.fechaBaja}">
                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"/>
                </h:outputText>
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Activo"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.activo}">
                </h:outputText>
            </p:column>

            <!--Esto agregue-->
            <f:facet name="footer"> 
                <p:commandButton  immediate="true" id="printButton" value="#{app['boton.print']}" 
                                  icon="ui-icon-print"
                                  action="#{clienteDataController.verReporte()}"  ajax="false" /> 
            </f:facet> 
        </p:dataTable>
```

Método guardar en *clienteController* de tipo *Request*:

```
public void guardar() {
    try {
        /*CON ESTAS  COSAS PERSISTO EL CLIENTE*/
        //----------------------------------------------------------------
        //persona.setIdtipodocumento(tipoDocumento);
        //personaFacade.create(persona);
        // cliente.setIdpersona(persona.getIdpersona());
        //clienteFacade.create(cliente);
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------
        persona.setIdtipodocumento(tipoDocumento);
        personaFacade.create(persona);
        cliente.setIdpersona(persona.getIdpersona());
        //Seteo la fecha de alta del cliente
        cliente.setFechaAlta(JSFUtil.getFechaActual());
        clienteFacade.create(cliente);
        JSFUtil.addSuccessMessage(rf.getMensajeArb("info.save"));
        // Limpiamos campos
        persona = new Persona();
        cliente = new Cliente();
        tipoDocumento = new Tipodocumento();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JSFUtil.addErrorMessage(e.getLocalizedMessage());

    }

}
```

Métodos de *clienteDataController* de tipo *View*:

```
 // Metodos
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    iniciar();
    //clienteList = clienteFacade.getClienteList();
}

public void iniciar() {
    clienteList = clienteFacade.getClienteList();
    //personaList = personaFacade.getPersonaList();
}
```

EJB, ClienteFacade:

```
  // retorna lista de personas
public List<Cliente> getClienteList() {
    return em.createNamedQuery("Cliente.findAll").getResultList();
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto captura del debug, el *clienteList* si me retorna resultados.

[image: clientList si tiene registros]

¿En que estoy Fallando?

Desde ya muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Saludos cordiales.

Comment: Hagamos un ejercicio, pasa el fragento del dataTable a la misma vista donde  haces el insert, y agrega un update=":form" para que se actualice toda la vista cuando hagas el insert, adicional imprime en consola los valores almacenados en la lista o corre en DEBUG para que veas si te esta regresando registros la Bd.

Comment: @Ventur ya lo hice , lo corri en modo debug y si me trae toda la informacion.

¿Tendra algo que ver la relacion entre persona y cliente de tipo one to one ?

Comment: MM el problema es que no te muestra datos tu data table, si dices que la lista `clienteDataController.clienteList` ¿si regresa datos?.

Comment: @Ventur sigue sin funcionar

Answer (score 0):

Debes hacer uso del update en la etiqueta del boton, par que una vez que se ejecute la acción actualice el formulario o alguna parte en específico de el:

```
<p:commandButton  immediate="true" id="printButton" 
    value="#{app['boton.print']}" icon="ui-icon-print"
    action="#{clienteDataController.verReporte()}"  ajax="false" 
    update=":form"/>
```

Puedes hacerlo directamente sobre tu dataTable, cambias el update **:form** por el del dataTable (:form:datatable). Saludos.

Comment: Hola rostan. 

La inserción la tengo en la pagina clienteInsert.xhtml
y el listado en clienteList.xhtml

¿Como haría en ese caso ?

Comment: @franciscocastillo Podrías agregar la vista donde se hace la inserción y por favor valiad si en BD los datos se registraron correctamente.

Comment: @Voiser , ¿necesitas que agregue el código en donde realizo la inserción ? o en el update agrego la vista ?

Comment: Desde donde llamas a clienteInsert.xhtml?. Otra pregunta por que no usaste un dialog en vez de un xhtml completo para insertar el usuario?

Comment: @franciscocastillo agrega el fragmento de donde  haces insert --> `p:Button `,y confirma si en la tabla existen esos registros,

Comment: @Ventur                         <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-check" value="Registrar" update="pgPersona,mensaje" actionListener="#{clienteController.guardar()}">

                        </p:commandButton>

Los datos si existen en la tabla Persona y en la tabla Cliente

Comment: Amigos seguí revisando el código y encontré el error. El problema no es de actualización sino de mapeo entre las entidades persona y cliente.

corregí eso y el datatable funciona correctamente.

No quise eliminar la publicación , porque había respuestas, supongo que como la pregunta no tiene nada que ver con el problema y la solucion deberia cerrarse. 

Muchas gracias a todos por la ayuda. 

Saludos cordiales.

Comment: Felicidades @franciscocastillo, que bueno que hayas dado con el problema, en todo caso cierra postea la solucion como respuesta y cierra la pregunta. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

copie el código de tu dataTable e hice un dommie  y  si me muestra datos tu tabla.

Coloca  este fragmento en tu código, solo reemplazando el nombre del MB y ajustando las propiedades de algunnas columnas:

```
            <p:dataTable id="datatable" paginator="true" 
                         rows="7" value="#{testDataTable.clienteList}" var="item" 
                         rowKey="#{item.NDI}" 
                         selectionMode="single" > 
                <p:ajax event="rowSelect" 
                        oncomplete="PF('editwidgetVar').show();" 
                        update="@form"/> 


                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Apellido"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.apellido}"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Nombres"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.nombres}"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="DNI"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.NDI}"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Dirección"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.direccion}"/>

                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Télefono"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.telefono}"/>

                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Fecha de Alta"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.fechaAlta}">
                        <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"/>
                    </h:outputText>
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Fecha de Baja"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.fechaBaja}">
                        <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"/>
                    </h:outputText>
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Activo"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.activo}">
                    </h:outputText>
                </p:column>

                <f:facet name="footer"> 
                    <p:commandButton  immediate="true" id="printButton" value="#" 
                                      icon="ui-icon-print"
                                      action="#"  ajax="false" /> 
                </f:facet> 
            </p:dataTable>
```

En el metodo que obtiene la lista, recorrela e imprime en consola los valores que trar por ejemplo:

```
 clienteList.forEach((p) -> {
        System.out.println(p.getNombres());
        });
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Buen día amigo,

Lo que pasa es que antes de hacer el insert en la tabla ya tienes los registros guardados, lo que tienes que hacer es colocar un evento que te recargue la pagina después de hacer el insert para que vuelva a consultar y refresque los registros de la tabla.